# Passing a SQL returned data value and passing it to a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a page that is returning the date and time from a database. I have a method in another class that takes that date/time and tells me how long ago the date was.

The time ago class works fine when I pass a generic date. And I can retrieve and display the date just fine. The problem exists when I try to pass the retrieved records date to the method.

I have tried different variations on the passing the date time to the GetTimeAgoView() method.

Am I passing it wrong?

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_ticketDateOpened" Text='<%# Eval("ticketDateOpened") %>' runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="lbl_timeago" runat="server" Text='<%#  GetTimeAgoView(DateTime.Parse(Eval("ticketDateOpened")))%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code-behind file

```
 protected string GetTimeAgoView(DateTime dt)
        {
            return HelperTimeAgo.GetDateAgoTime(dt) ;
        }
```

The date is stored in the SQL database as a DateTime object.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Depending on how I try to tackle it, The best overloaded method match for 'TroubleTicketing.Default.GetTimeAgoView(System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the solution.

When the Eval Statement is processed, it converts my ticketDateOpened date to a string. I had to convert the string BACK to a date/time object using Convert.ToDateTime, since my method wanted a datetime variable.

Hope this helps someone in the future!